# Server terminating the process before complete the full execution in PHP

Tags: php, web-hosting

I am trying to run a php file through cron job. It starts the running well but after a certain time period,the server is terminating it's execution.

So that I can't get my desired output. I am taking the output in a text file. After start the cron, it store some output into the text file but before completing full execution, it is terminating the process.

I also called mail function at beginning and ending of the file. But I only got the beginning message.

I set the `max_time`, `max_memory` to the infinite and also checked the settings from `php_info()`.

Everything is ok there but file is not completing its execution successfully. I am able to run the file through browser but it requires a very long time.

So I must do it with others way like cron. If any one provide me a better solution in this regard, I will be grateful.

Comment: did you set set_time_limit(0)?

Comment: yes I did into both code and ini file.

Comment: idea: when you run the cron job you are using the cli version of PHP and this cli version is using a different php.ini. This php.ini might have different settings. Next step: find out which php.ini your cli php version is using and what the max_time... settings are in this php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Turn off safe_mode in php.ini and change maximum execution time by adding

> set_time_limit(0)

At the beginning of your script
[php set_time_limit function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)